# PHPUnit Test Cases not executing

Tags: php, phpunit

Trying to be a good back-end developer by jumping onto the bandwagon of Test-Driven Development I have just installed PHPUnit via composer. I then ran command vendor/bin/phpunit and could see that PHPUnit was correctly installed.

Below is my file structure:

```
-fileserver
  src
  tests/
  vendor
  composer.json
  composer.lock
  index.php
  phpunit.xml
```

Inside phpunit.xml file I have the contents below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <phpunit colors="true">
    <testsuites>
      <testsuite name="File Server Test Suite">
        <directory>./fileserver/tests/</directory>
      </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
  </phpunit>
```

If I run vendor/bin/phpunit I can see that my configuration file has been loaded but no tests run.

I basically created a simple test file inside tests folder and extended PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase. All my test use the psr-4 namespace PhpUnitTest.

composer.json

```
//Other part excluded
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": { 
    "FileServer\\": "src" ,
    "PhpUnitTest\\": "tests"
  }
```

Sample test class

```
namespace PhpUnitTest;

 class StupidTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
 {
   public function testTrueIsTrue()
   {
     $foo = true;
     $this->assertTrue($foo);
   }
 }
```

However below is the output I get:

```
PS C:\wamp\www\fileserver> vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 3.7.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\wamp\www\fileserver\phpunit.xml



  Time: 3.53 seconds, Memory: 1.25Mb

←[30;43m←[2KNo tests executed!
←[0m←[2KPS C:\wamp\www\fileserver>
```

What have I missed? Why my test case has not been executed? Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not adding the composer-generated autoloader to your phpunit.xml file. Set the `bootstrap` attribute on the `phpunit` tag. The paths to your testsuites are incorrect, too. The path should be relative to the `phpunit.xml` file, so you should loose the `fileserver/` bit in the path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php" colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="File Server Test Suite">
            <directory>tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

That ought to do it

Comment: Thanks. I have, however, did as you instructed but still could not see any test results.... :-(

Comment: @LuyandaSiko: Didn't spot the other problem: the paths to your testsuites are wrong, too

Comment: Thank you Elias. Clearly the tutorial I followed is outdated...... My test ran successfully.... :-)